# why does the console show error: The activator slot must be bound, when I have already bounded it?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to display this page as a dialog box in another page. This code is taken from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4fIObUYiHw&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9g0MQZfHwKcuB0Yswgb3gA5&index=23 it works for him but not me. I also get an error on console : **The activator slot must be bound, try `'<template v-slot:activator="{ on }"><v-btn v-on="on">'.` can you help me by solving this error  found in console?**

```
  <template>
<v-dialog  max-width="600px">
    <v-btn slot="activator" v-on="hello" class="success">Add New Project</v-btn>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title>
        <h2>Add a New Project</h2>
      </v-card-title>
    </v-card>
    
  </v-dialog>
  
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {

    return {

    }
  }
}
</script>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is give in that warning you should do :

```
<template>
   <v-dialog  max-width="600px">
     <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
       <v-btn  v-on="on" class="success">Add New Project</v-btn>
     </template>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title>
        <h2>Add a New Project</h2>
      </v-card-title>
    </v-card>
   </v-dialog>
  
</template>
```